# How to push Nested Dict Data to csv file in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a csv file from the data below using python3:-

I am recicving the data in this dict format from a for loop :-

```
data = [{('Apr', 'Apurv'): 10, ('Mar', 'Apurv'): 58}, {('Apr', 'Smriti'): 12, ('Mar', 'Smriti'): 70}, {('Apr', 'Pankhuri'): 12, ('Mar', 'Pankhuri'): 73}, {('Apr', 'Parth'): 21, ('Mar', 'Parth'): 101}]
```

I need fetch the header and rows from data so that i can push data to csv.

`header = ["Name", 'Apr', 'March']` # This could be more depending on the months present in data

And row should be like :

```
row1 = ["Apurv", 10, 58]

row2 = ["Smriti", 12, 70]

row3 = ["Pankhuri, 12, 73]

row4 = ["Parth", 21, 103]


rows = [row1, row2, row3, row4]

with open("smriti.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(header)
    csvwriter.writerow(rows)
```

I need to put each name and month as different columns and insert the rows with respective name and count values corresponding to it.

The output should look like this :-

[image]

I am trying to use csv library in python.

Can anybody suggest how i can do this ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), and provide a [mre]. "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code to help you experiment with:

```
import csv

data = [{('Apr', 'Apurv'): 10, ('Mar', 'Apurv'): 58},
        {('Apr', 'Smriti'): 12, ('Mar', 'Smriti'): 70},
        {('Apr', 'Pankhuri'): 12, ('Mar', 'Pankhuri'): 73},
        {('Apr', 'Parth'): 21, ('Mar', 'Parth'): 101}]

header = ["Name"]

result = []

for item in data:
    line = {}
    for index, element in enumerate(item):
        # Collect header elements
        if element[0] not in header:
            header.append(element[0])

        # Fill table content
        if index == 0:
            line["Name"] = element[1]
        
        line[element[0]] = item[element[0], element[1]]

        if index == 1:
            result.append(line)

# Double-check the data
print(header)
print(result)

# Create the csv file
with open('smriti.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(result)
```